# Unable to load a suite in Robot Framework IDE (RIDE)

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

1. I have a directory containing three test suites in Robot Framework. All three test suites are in .txt format
2. When I launch Robot framewrok-RIDE and navigate to the directory in  the RIDE GUI, I see only two suites; while I can see the other one from file system (in my windows 7 machine)

Why am I not finding it from RIDE?
I tried to create a new suite with the same name (as of the suite which is missing from RIDE GUI). I get the error "Same file already exists"!
How to fix it?

Comment: can you show us the tree within whatever application you're using?

Comment: The test tree is like this: C:\Robot\Test\ABC\ (is the parent directory). It has test1.txt, test2.txt and test3.txt. test1.txt and test3.txt are shown up. But not test2.txt

Comment: When you say you "launch robot and navigate to the directory", what do you mean? robot has no way to "navigate to the directory". Are you actually talking about RIDE?

Comment: ah, yes. I meant RIDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem.
When I open ride, I was actually getting an error message saying: Not found 'Suite Setup' in ${SETTINGS}. There was a formatting error in testcase.txt file.